# iTunes account balance to cash

Tags: itunes

Can I Change my iTunes account credit to cash or used it for something so I can get money  ? So can someone help me on this because I load $400 on my iTunes account and in need it back now 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this page on Apple's site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202359).

Relevant portion is repeated here:

> You can't redeem or return iTunes or Apple Music Gift Cards or unused
>   store credit balances for cash, except as required by law. If your
>   jurisdiction allows for refund of redeemed gift balances, you can
>   request a refund by contacting [iTunes Store Support](https://expresslane.apple.com/GetproductgroupList.do?&PRKEYS=131629&category_id=SC0002&symptom_id=20180), selecting a
>   support category and topic, and including the following information in
>   your request detail:
>
> - Your Apple ID.
> - The store credit refund amount.
> - Your current shipping address.